# Breeze.js with Entity Framework. List of base class and sub class elements

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

See this example

```
public class A {
    public int Id {get;set}

    public C MyC {get; set;}
    [Foreign Key("MyC")]
    public int MyCId {get;set;}
}

public class B : A {
}

public class C {
    public int Id {get;set}

    public ICollection<A> As{get;set;}
    public ICollection<B> Bs{get;set;}
}
```

On the server side I can do

```
 someC.Bs.ToList()
```

and it will be the same as

```
someC.As.OfType<B>().ToList()
```

However, on the client side an entity someC will have an empty Bs since the foreign key is on A. It is also not possible to use inverse property on Bs since the Id is on A.

Is there any way of having both the Bs and the As list populated on the client side without

```
public class A {
    public int Id {get;set}

    public C A_C {get; set;}
    [Foreign Key("A_C")]
    public int A_CId {get;set;}
}

public class B : A {
    public C B_C {get; set;}
    [Foreign Key("B_C")]
    public int B_CId {get;set;}
}
```

This kind of destroys the purpose of inheritance.